# Simple Statement on Riesel Numbers $k2^n-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Riesel numbers are those $k$ such that $k2^n-1$ is never prime for any $n$. How do we prove a simple statement saying:

There doesn't exist $k$ such that $k2^n-1$ is prime *for all* $n$.

Comment: Does $n$ start with zero or one when considering "for all $n$"?

Comment: $0$, although I do not think it makes too much difference.

Comment: If we allow $n=0$ then $k=p+1$ for some prime $p$, so perhaps it makes things a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we begin a chain of primes with $k2^0 - 1 = p$, and that $k2^1 - 1 = 2p+1$ is also prime, hence by definition $p$ is a [Sophie Germain prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime).

If we assume the chain of primes $k2^n - 1$ continues infinitely, then we have an infinite [Cunningham chain (of the first kind)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain), which is [known to be impossible](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1989-53-188/S0025-5718-1989-0979939-8/).

Since the proof is short, we give it.  For $k=1,2$ it's evident that $2^4 - 1$ is composite, so we consider only $k \gt 2$.

Now with $p_0 = p = k - 1 \gt 1$ as above, one shows by induction that $p_n = k2^n - 1$ takes the form:

$$ p_n = 2^n p_0 + (2^n - 1) $$

Setting $n = p_0 - 1 \gt 0$ and using [Fermat's Little Thm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to the effect that $2^{p_0-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p_0}$, we see $p_0 | p_{p_0-1}$.  Thus $p_{p_0-1}$ is composite.